# Backbone + Webpack `Uncaught TypeError: _.create is not a function`, underscore not loading?

Tags: backbone.js, webpack

I'm using webpack for the first time. When requiring backbone, it seems to not be loading underscore properly, since I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: _.create is not a function` in `backbone.js:1892` in my browser.

**main.js**

```
'use strict';
import Backbone from 'backbone';
Backbone.$('body');  // Doesn't error
Backbone.View.extend({}); // Gives error
```

My webpack config can be found in this [boilerplate repo](https://github.com/andrewscwei/generator-vars-jekyll/blob/2dca4dab4a7f6420c609413f129cf5eebda91598/app/templates/.taskconfig#L49-L102).

```
└─┬ backbone@1.3.3
  └── underscore@1.8.3
```

***Update*** When I use backbone `v1.2.3`, it works fine. `v1.3.0+` causes this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue due to npm3's method of loading dependencies, combined with my webpack config.

I was using a directory for the `modulesDirectories` property.

```
modulesDirectories: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
]
```

Since npm3 loads dependencies in a flat way (all at the root `node_modules` dir, and version conflicts get put into the module's directory under a `node_modules` subdir, webpack was always importing underscore 1.7.x (a dependency of another module in my project) instead of the 1.8.3 that was in backbone's subdir.

Downgrading to backbone `v1.2.3` only worked because it was using the same version of underscore that my other dependency was using, so there was no conflict.

I removed the `modulesDirectories` completely, since it [has a default](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories). I could have also changed this to `modulesDirectories=['node_modules']` to get the same effect.